# Extracting all links from a webpage and storing into a data frame using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to extract the links from the following webpage: https://www.ine.es/dynt3/inebase/index.htm?padre=5608&capsel=5608#

For example, using Barcelona, I would have:

```
2.9.1 Indicadores de renta media y mediana https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30896&L=0
2.9.2 Distribución por fuente de ingresos https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30897&L=0
2.9.3 Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30898&L=0
2.9.4 Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo y tramos de edad https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30899&L=0
...
2.9.10 Indicadores demográficos https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30904&L=0
```

I would like to do this for all the `provinces`. When I run the following, I get an `NA`.

```
library(rvest)
out <- read_html("https://www.ine.es/dynt3/inebase/index.htm?padre=5608&capsel=5608#")

out %>% 
  html_attr("href")
```

**EDIT:**

The link is the following:

https://www.ine.es/dynt3/inebase/index.htm?padre=5608

There are two sections which are not expanded. I can use the following:

```
library(rvest)

lnk <- "https://www.ine.es/dynt3/inebase/index.htm?padre=5608"
out <- read_html(lnk)

x <- out %>% 
  html_nodes('ol') %>% 
  html_nodes('li') %>% 
  html_nodes('a') %>% 
  html_attr('href') %>% 
  str_sub(-4, -1) %>% 
  paste(lnk, "&capsel=", ., sep = "")
```

To give me this output:

```
"https://www.ine.es/dynt3/inebase/index.htm?padre=5608&capsel=5650" "https://www.ine.es/dynt3/inebase/index.htm?padre=5608&capsel=7132"
```

Each one of these links expands the two sections and now I am trying to extract each of these links (contained within the sections).

**EDIT2**

Doing the same thing as above to get the links of the expanded sections I run:

```
x[2] %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes('ol') %>% 
  html_nodes('li') %>% 
  html_nodes('a') %>% 
  html_attr('href') %>% 
  str_sub(-4, -1) %>% 
  paste(lnk, "&capsel=", ., sep = "")
```

Which gives me:

```
 [1] "https://www.ine.es/dynt3/inebase/index.htm?padre=5608&capsel=5650" "https://www.ine.es/dynt3/inebase/index.htm?padre=5608&capsel=7132"
 [3] "https://www.ine.es/dynt3/inebase/index.htm?padre=5608&capsel=5609" "https://www.ine.es/dynt3/inebase/index.htm?padre=5608&capsel=5652"
 [5] "https://www.ine.es/dynt3/inebase/index.htm?padre=5608&capsel=5653" "https://www.ine.es/dynt3/inebase/index.htm?padre=5608&capsel=5654"
```

The first two results correspond to the links which I have already obtained the previous part. I am interested in the links after the first 2.

Now I want to extract all of the links from the expanded out section of the "Provincia" i.e. the white part in the below image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a series of user defined functions/helpers which extract the expand url in each case and finally grab the details that you want as a `dataframe`. You can combine all those `dataframes` into one with `map2_dfr` from `purrr`. I use `map2_dfr` because you also need to alter the index in the `nth-child` part of the css selector, when retrieving the details you wanted from each `li` listing. This means the `get_details` function needs 2 args as input i.e. the url and the index.

> [`map2_dfr()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html) is a variant of `map()` that allows you to iterate
> over multiple arguments simultaneously.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

get_expand_url <- function(url) {
  link <- read_html(url) %>%
    html_node(".inebase_capitulo:nth-child(2) .desplegar") %>%
    html_attr("href") %>%
    url_absolute(url)
  return(link)
}

get_provincias_links <- function(url) {
  provincias <- read_html(url) %>%
    html_nodes(".respuestas > .inebase_capitulo:nth-child(2) .inebase_capitulo [id^=c_]") %>%
    html_attr("href") %>%
    url_absolute(url)
  return(provincias)
}

get_details <- function(provincia_url, n) {
  node <- read_html(provincia_url) %>%
    html_node(sprintf(".respuestas > .inebase_capitulo:nth-child(2) .inebase_capitulo:nth-child(%i)", n))

  provincia <- node %>%
    html_node(xpath = ".//span/following-sibling::text()[1]") %>%
    html_text(trim = T)

  df <- data.frame(
    index = node %>%
      html_nodes(".indice:nth-child(n+3)") %>%
      html_text(),

    title = node %>%
      html_nodes("span +.titulo") %>%
      html_text(),

    link = node %>%
      html_nodes("span +.titulo") %>%
      html_attr("href") %>% url_absolute(start_url)
  )
  df$provincia <- provincia
  return(df)
}

start_url <- "https://www.ine.es/dynt3/inebase/index.htm?padre=5608"

expand_url <- get_expand_url(start_url)
provincias_links <- get_provincias_links(expand_url)
indices <- 1:length(provincias_links)

df <- purrr::map2_dfr(provincias_links, indices, .f = get_details)
```

Comment: Amazing thank you, more than what I wanted!